# Changing css property with onscroll

Tags: javascript

how do I change css property like background color onscroll using JavaScript.

```
window.onscroll = () =>{
if(document.body.scrollTop = 30){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey"} 
else{document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a listener to you `window` object for the "scroll" event, in the handler you can use `window.scrollY` value in order to know how much page is scrolled.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () =>{
    if(window.scrollY > 30){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey"} 
    else{
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    } 
})
```

```html
    <body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in egestas lectus, non porta nunc. Vivamus id pharetra purus. Vivamus semper pellentesque dui. Duis cursus fermentum nunc, et tempor leo imperdiet luctus. Fusce a nibh id felis faucibus feugiat a eget diam. Fusce ante ex, aliquam at velit eget, aliquet laoreet ipsum. Quisque iaculis fermentum consectetur. Etiam facilisis nec nisl sit amet eleifend. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque varius libero sed nunc lacinia gravida. Vestibulum at ex ac magna vehicula lobortis. Morbi rhoncus massa non ligula pulvinar dictum. Curabitur turpis libero, maximus eget pharetra non, luctus id orci. Integer id augue id diam ultrices dignissim.

    Quisque et ante vel orci auctor imperdiet ac ut nisi. Ut sollicitudin at neque in imperdiet. Quisque eu laoreet nisi. Duis id venenatis diam, in lacinia erat. Quisque ullamcorper fringilla mauris, vel iaculis augue iaculis ac. Mauris luctus, quam vel dignissim accumsan, sem libero sollicitudin justo, et condimentum augue lectus vel nibh. Aliquam sit amet dolor vel urna malesuada sagittis id quis ipsum. Vivamus ut arcu porta, auctor massa ac, suscipit tortor. Mauris in bibendum sapien. Sed quam dui, aliquam nec tellus tincidunt, vehicula vestibulum nunc. Donec aliquet tempor diam nec convallis. Integer a leo vitae nunc porta venenatis ac eu arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus quis urna neque. In dapibus purus sit amet lectus finibus pellentesque. Vivamus viverra sed enim pharetra dapibus.

    In accumsan mollis interdum. Phasellus pulvinar purus nec libero porttitor, ut sollicitudin arcu consectetur. Nullam justo mi, feugiat sit amet sollicitudin volutpat, commodo id metus. Donec vitae sem eu lorem consectetur lacinia. Fusce consequat erat id metus pharetra, quis interdum purus bibendum. Phasellus justo magna, imperdiet non nulla id, porta aliquet ante. Nam dignissim diam ut quam eleifend convallis. Phasellus tincidunt odio urna, a pharetra magna blandit eleifend. Integer euismod nisl pellentesque magna varius sodales. Vestibulum consequat sagittis bibendum. Ut cursus, velit quis suscipit auctor, felis urna iaculis eros, nec finibus augue ligula eu ex. Ut nec sapien nulla. Integer blandit mattis venenatis. Donec convallis luctus odio, a mattis massa varius vehicula. Aliquam a semper tortor. Phasellus nec purus id purus fringilla sodales.

    Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla feugiat rhoncus pulvinar. Pellentesque quis nunc dignissim, gravida ipsum sed, venenatis tellus. Quisque ultricies ipsum eget odio tempus, nec aliquam tellus sodales. Ut vitae ultricies diam. Duis iaculis diam venenatis nulla hendrerit efficitur. Sed aliquet faucibus finibus. Suspendisse cursus scelerisque placerat. Aenean laoreet a ipsum et viverra.

    Integer non nisl accumsan, vestibulum enim ac, auctor purus. Vivamus eget condimentum nulla. Nunc faucibus elementum arcu, sed pretium augue posuere vitae. Suspendisse maximus dapibus enim, et dictum nisl imperdiet a. Aliquam a laoreet tortor, vel placerat felis. Fusce tristique orci ligula, et tincidunt odio sagittis eu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin aliquam, dolor at posuere facilisis, neque leo imperdiet arcu, sit amet sollicitudin mi nibh id erat. Quisque sit amet lectus quis lectus aliquam ullamcorper varius id turpis. Vestibulum nec velit quis justo facilisis ullamcorper at vel neque. Donec sodales varius leo non vehicula. Proin sed molestie velit. Pellentesque ac porttitor eros. Sed at ullamcorper dolor.

    Sed consequat viverra ex, eu pretium velit vehicula et. Donec vestibulum commodo leo id molestie. Praesent pharetra eros ac leo aliquam, sit amet interdum sem mattis. Ut tincidunt condimentum mauris, et sollicitudin felis. Aenean volutpat dapibus diam a fringilla. Sed iaculis faucibus nunc, eget dictum nulla auctor vel. Nullam sollicitudin porttitor accumsan. Nulla et orci ligula. Mauris imperdiet finibus ligula convallis bibendum. Nullam magna lectus, sodales non velit sit amet, dapibus porttitor sem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

    Curabitur eu ligula eu nisl dapibus vulputate quis id ante. Ut vitae arcu in tortor ultricies pretium eu sit amet urna. Pellentesque malesuada libero nunc, quis elementum quam tristique at. Nulla mollis et dui a gravida. Nulla iaculis finibus sem sit amet ornare. Praesent pellentesque bibendum velit, ut semper odio dictum consequat. Donec feugiat venenatis lacus, at rutrum libero venenatis eget. Donec tempor lorem neque. Vestibulum eu quam vehicula, facilisis elit quis, scelerisque ipsum. Suspendisse aliquet arcu at arcu vestibulum dictum.

    Ut ut pharetra sapien, nec posuere dolor. Nunc convallis viverra ipsum in tempor. Donec interdum viverra mauris, vel placerat lectus ultricies non. Etiam interdum vestibulum aliquet. Duis luctus vel elit eget condimentum. Sed molestie pulvinar dictum. Aliquam libero enim, eleifend at vehicula et, porttitor ac turpis. Duis quis urna elit.

    Morbi facilisis volutpat turpis eget tempus. Aliquam eu dolor ornare, lacinia nibh ut, interdum ligula. Aliquam finibus egestas dapibus. Sed at semper nulla. Sed eu sodales risus. Sed interdum ante nec mi suscipit, in aliquet erat posuere. Sed velit risus, dapibus nec posuere ac, vulputate sed dui. Sed lobortis enim in ipsum imperdiet rhoncus. Nulla eu urna quam. Nulla dapibus quis dui eu consectetur. Cras feugiat, ex in finibus fringilla, orci erat congue urna, sed consequat quam dolor ac enim. Integer facilisis euismod nunc quis auctor. Nam iaculis ullamcorper magna, sed feugiat neque volutpat vel. Integer varius ultrices erat quis interdum. Proin sit amet sagittis sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

    In at ullamcorper ipsum. Nam ultrices, lectus et gravida posuere, est tortor dignissim ante, at sodales ipsum ex tempor nisl. Cras fermentum tempus malesuada. Nam fermentum ante in massa tristique, porttitor fermentum turpis iaculis. Aenean et neque sed lacus auctor facilisis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis non suscipit nulla. Nullam at magna dui. Duis fringilla vitae arcu at mollis. Praesent ultrices efficitur dolor, eget tempus dolor rutrum eu. Ut condimentum sodales lectus ut lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Sed nec est in dui dictum blandit. Cras eu neque felis. Integer luctus faucibus augue, quis luctus erat scelerisque eu.
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Scroll slowly because it will render fast or You can console or alert it inside the condition. So you can understand it.

```js
window.onscroll = () =>{
let element = window.pageYOffset;
element = Math.round(element)
console.log(element)
if(element == 30){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"} 
else{document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"} 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="height:2000px; width:100px">
 
  </div>
</body>
```